# Handling Complex Queries in Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a database consisting of reviews, follow, and users. Where users following other users is a many to many relationship modeled by the follow table. In total my schema looks as follows:

- follow (collection) - key: fid

  - following (uid)
  - follower (uid)
- review (collection) - key: rid

  - title (string)
  - author (uid)
  - posted (timestamp)
- user (collection) - key: uid

  - created (timestamp)
  - email (string)

I want to run a query to get the `T` most recent reviews where the user is following the author. In a SQL environment I would do this with two `joins` and a `where` clause.

Let us consider a user following `n` people, where each person they're following has `m` reviews. I was considering finding all reviews for all of the `n` people one is following, then discarding all those older than `T`, but recognize the number of reads will be `n*m`. As we can easily expect `n > 100` and `m > 1000`, this is not a viable solution. I recognize there is probably no great way to do this in firestore. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: [The top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153332/7834942) to a similar question is giving an `nk` (where `k` is an arbitrary limit) solution for a number of reads. It is also answering an easier question: "get the `T` most recent reviews for each person one is following" **not** "get the `T` most recent reviews of all people one is following." [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/54741889/7834942), suggests keeping an updated copy of all followers in every review then doing a `whereArrayContains` clause to find reviews one is following. But if user `A` follows a user `B` who has `B_m` reviews, we will perform `B_m` writes for each follow or unfollow. We will also be massively denormalizing our database, storing and updating the same information in thousands of locations.

Comment: Hi @thedeg123 indeed, Firestore is not meant for this type of queries. It would be better for you to read the data into arrays/variables and do the search within this variables. I, however, have found a similar question to yours, where there are some interesting information. Could you please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979375/firestore-how-to-structure-a-feed-and-follow-system) to verify if this helps you?

Comment: @gso_gabriel only somewhat, the top answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153332/7834942) is essentially a hierarchical interpretation of what I already have. Additionally, it gives the same query that I was considering above! With the adjustment of  imposing an arbitrary limit of k reviews per user, implying nk reads instead of nm. The next answer is better (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741889/7834942) , but if user A follows a user B who has B_m reviews, we will perform  B_m writes for each follow.

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems highly relational so the best option for you is to switch to a relational database. The only way to get this to work in firestore is to either completely denormalize your data or chain a ton of queries together to get all of the data you need, neither is ideal in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

there's a way that worked for me which is creating a link between indexes, how is that ? going to firestore => indexes and add index with this you can link the fields you want to query on and then you will be able to do this query in your code