# Show only followed users content using firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I created an app where I must show data according to whether current user follows post publisher or not. For example, if user A follows user B show B's posts to A. My current firestore db structure provided below:

Users (collection) -> userId (document) -> Following (collection) -> followingUserId (document)

I just want to know how I can show only posts from followed users. Your db structure suggestions is highly appreciated also. Thanks in advance

DB images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Besides that, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for reply. I edited my question above you can find DB images there. So far I have tried nothing special on that problem because I need insight on how to approach to this kind of situations.

Comment: I think [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52153332/5246885) might help, right?