# Users following in order to get followed users posts database design and update from app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nosql

My use case: 
`UserA` can create post.
`Users B,C,D...` can follow `userA` in order to see his posts on their screen.
My design idea:
`/users` --> registered users
`/posts` --> collection where users store their posts (in app I have screen that list all posts by date not related to following users so this is what everybody see).
/feed --> when post is created I copy here photo, title, short description and tags this documents has less data than posts.

In user document I have:

```
/users
  -userId
    - followers
      -userIdB
      -userIdC
      -userIdD
    - followings
```

Now when `UserA` create new post:

- it is stored in `/posts`
- it is copied with less info in `/feed`
- fetch list of `followers` and copy with less info in `/users/userB...C...D/feed` collection.
- if `userIdE` starts to follow `userA` I copy `userA` posts to `/users/.../userIdE/feed`

When I list posts from all I fetch data from `/feed`
When I list posts from users I follow I fetch from `/users/myId/feed`
Until this point I think that design is good (I hope).

This is proof of concept that real users will use but I am limited to my app I can't use firebase functions as client doesn't want to start with paid plan.
What could be a problem to make all this data copy to: feed, users/feed from user phone in terms of cost?
I am also scared that somebody can sit and follow/unfollow same user which will make coping data million times.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979375/firestore-how-to-structure-a-feed-and-follow-system/52153332#52153332) will help.

Comment: I read it and if I understand it I can't use it as there there is /posts/userX/[hisPosts] but if I follow 5 users I need to get paging data sorted by date. Not only from one user.

Comment: Can you check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35RlydUf6xo&t=530) once?

Comment: That is exactly what I did.

Comment: I believe Firebase functions would be the best way to ensure that the client's server can sanity-check the requests and volume of those requests too.
Instead of copying the actual data, it might be better to just copy references to it.
It will be difficult to understand all  constraints from stack overflow post.

Comment: Please contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) if you are worried about security issues to share details here. And you may have look at this [link](https://medium.com/@garyalexanderpiong/building-a-working-instagram-clone-using-flutter-and-firebase-1c9f9bb960ef) which may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I believe Firebase functions would be the best way to ensure that the client's server can sanity-check the requests and volume of those requests too.

Instead of copying the actual data, it might be better to just copy references to it.

It will be difficult to understand all  constraints from stack overflow post.

Please contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) if you are worried about security issues to share details here. And you may have look at this [link](https://medium.com/@garyalexanderpiong/building-a-working-instagram-clone-using-flutter-and-firebase-1c9f9bb960ef) which may be helpful